# Problems with Fragment enter transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I'm using a device running on Android 5.0, the `minSdk` is 21 and the `targetSdk` is 22.

**App description**

I'm on an app with 2 activities, activity A contains a `GridView` with pictures and text and activity B contains one `ImageView`, one `TextView` and a fragment. This fragment contains a list of images associated to a text.
When clicking on an image of activity A, there is a shared element transition which moves the image and the text to the `ImageView` and the `TextView` of activity B. I also set a fade transition between activity A and B. The fragment is added dynamically to activity B in the `onCreate()` method. I set and enter and exit transition to the fragment:

```
 MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
 myFragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
 myFragment.setExitTransition(new Slide);
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG)
                .commit();
```

About the fragment exit transition, I used a trick, when pressing the back button, I replace the fragment with another one to force it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myFragment.isVisible()) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment())
                .commit();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The theme of my app is a child of `Theme.Material` so I didn't define

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
```

nor

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

(I tried with and it made no difference).

**App problem**

My issue concerns the fragment enter transition which is not working properly, while the exit transition works fine. 
I tried different cases:

- no explicitly defined activity transition: there is no enter transition, the fragment is already there when the shared element transition is playing.
- define an activity transition with java in activity A and B:

  `getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());
  getWindow().setExitTransition(new Fade());`

  The result is the same as no explicit activity transition defined.
- define an activity transition with XML:

  `<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/fade</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/fade</item>`

  The result is that the fragment will enter by fading and the `Fragment.setEnterTransition()` is ignored.
- define the fragment enter transition in XML: 
  `<item name="android:fragmentEnterTransition">@transition/fade</item>`
  the result is that it is totally ignored, all the cases before will happen the same.

I tried other things to make it work like this: `myFragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);` but nothing...
I also tried to set a click listener on the `ImageView` and add the fragment only on clicking the image and it worked ! From this, I thought that there might be a problem in the timing of the fragment transition compared to the activity lifecycle, so I tried putting the code in the `onResume()` method but still nothing.

Then I tried to use a `postDelayed()` method:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
myFragment.setExitTransition(new Slide);
mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

and it also worked!

At last I tried to add an empty fragment and then replace it by `myFragment`:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
myFragment.setExitTransition(new Slide);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Fragment)
                .commit();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG)
                .commit();
```

But still nothing...

So now I'm wondering if there is something I missing to make it work without using a trick... And the thing is I know it can work because I started to work on the app maybe 5 months ago and it was working!! So I don't know what happened, I didn't update my Android version.

**Bonus bug**: It is still about the fragment enter transition. Before having the app like I described before, I tried a version without shared element transition. And if I don't set a transition name to the `TextView` of Activity B, the fragment will never have an enter transition. But same as before, if set in a onclicklistener method, it will work. I tried this on 2 devices running on Android 5.0.x and the transition was not working. I tried on a device with Android 5.1.1 and the transition worked (without changing anything in the code)! Still no idea on what is happening...

So my final question is: What is the explanation of this behavior and is there a way of making it work without using a trick?

Comment: I think I am stuck in a similar problem. Only difference I am stuck in an exit transition. Did you get around solving this?

Comment: Same here, using onCreate is no answer for me because i'm adding some slide transition to RecyclerView and circular reveal to a view. My problem is when i have appbarLayout enterTransition does not work, if i remove it, then it starts to work. U haven't seen a api that is buggy as this and very very poorly documented.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the enter and exit transitions for the fragment in its OnCreate instead. That seemed to have worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use setCustomAnimations from the FragmentTransaction class.

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.setCustomAnimations(R.id.inAnim, R.id.outAnim,R.id.inAnim, R.id.outAnim)
                .replace(R.id.container, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG)
                .commit();

This way you can define an animation per transition.

Comment: Downvoted because this is the old way of doing this. The OP is using the newer Transition API

Answer (score 0):

I was working defining fragment transitions this way some years ago, now i faced this issue as well. I looked at my old code and found the answer there. In my case the layout had several ViewGroups and i wanted to have different enterTransitions for the children. For me the issue got solved by adding `android:transitionGroup="false"` to my root container of the layout file.